# using recyclerview for 5-7 cards vs scrollview

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, scrollview

I have recyclerview with 7 cards, that include something data like this:

[image: card example]

Some cards have photos (from 2 to 6), photos is attached from gallery by user;

Cards include different components, like switchers, textviews, edittexts.
Some options in cards can remove some cards, or add some new edittexts into card;

**What is the problem?** For as long time as i programmed this, i got some problems, like many listeners for update data from one card to second, because in some cards i have recyclerview for photos inside. Too much rows of code.

**Question:** Maybe need to use scrollview instead of it in this situation, creating cards in xml?
I think, i could explain my problem, sorry for my English.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The advantage of using RecyclerView - application does not hold **all** views in memory. It holds **only** `ViewHolder` (as much instances as needed to display all visible elements), which are reused to display different data depends on what you pass to `onBindViewHolder` method.

Hence, if you have mostly cards with simillar XML and they can not fit to screen all at the same time, your choice - RecyclerView.

Comment: thanks for answer, but is it normally to use recyclerview inside card?)

Comment: If your nested recyclerview (inside card) scroll orientation differ from main recyclerview it's ok. For example: main - scrolls vertically, nested - scrolls horizontally. But when you have nested scroll with same orientation - it is horrible UX, never do like this ;)